# How can i create a css arrow?

Tags: html, css

I want to create this arrow with pure css:
[Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQUmm.jpg)

But i have no idea how i can do this. Can someone create an example for me? I think i need pseudo-elements like before and after. I have only found some triangle generators. If possible i want create the arrow in one of the following elements:

```html
 <span class='arrow'></span> 
 <p class='arrow'></p>
```

Comment: To be honest, cheat and use fontawesome, it is going to save you a boatload of headache

Comment: Just use html entities: http://htmlarrows.com/